# How to display all products without using ListMatchingProducts in the Amazon MWS Products API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I have integrated the MWS API for my store. The issue is I was not able to get list of all products which I have submitted from feeds and also available products in Amazon store in account.

I have tried all the api of MWS no any api giving all products.

In Listmatchingproducts api it needs query parameter but for product listing there should not be query parameter required.

So for all product listing which api will be used and how?

Answer (score 3):

In order for you to retrieve all of your products without input parameters, you can use the Reports API to request an inventory report or active listings reports or any of the report types here: http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html#ReportTypeCategories__ListingsReports

You can call the Reports API just like the Products API, but there are extra steps involved.  You first request the report using the `RequestReport` operation, then you'll get back a `GeneratedReportId`.  Take that Id and call the `GetReport` operation and you'll get back the report once it's available.  If you need more than a report, but need to work with the data in some other way, you can just write a routine in whatever language you're using to parse out the data in memory.

Have you seen the client libraries?  They do most of the work already, just plug in your keys. https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/188-4747010-1589520?ie=UTF8&group=bde&section=reports&version=latest

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no specific API to call the product list available in your store. But you can get your products using Reports API (ReportType enumeration)
http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html#ReportTypeCategories__ListingsReports

There is multiple steps involve in order to work with reports.Here is the steps that involve to get the product listing.

1-RequestReport
2-GetReportRequestList (includes the ReportId when done)
3-GetReport

Have you tried Scratchpad. its for UK marketplace.
https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk/scratchpad/index.html